# Setting properties with reflection on static classes

Tags: c#, reflection, static

I want to make a static class that would load some settings from XML file and apply those settings to its own properties.

I am trying to use the following code but I don't really know what to give to the SetValue method since the class for which we want to set the property is static.

```
// some code removed ...
// Settings is a static class
Type settingsType = typeof(Settings);   

foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInformation in 
    settingsType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
{
    //  Determine if configured setting matches current setting based on name
    if (propertyInformation.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        //  Attempt to apply configured setting
        try
        {
            if (propertyInformation.CanWrite)
            {
                propertyInformation.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInformation.PropertyType, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), null);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to set properties on static classes with reflection?

Comment: `Settings` is **`internal sealed partial class Settings`** ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just pass `null` for the instance.

Comment: As per the documentation, it is ignored so you can pass anything at all. For readability, we usually call it like this:

```
prop.SetValue("ThisArgumentIsIgnoredForStaticMethods", value);
```